# Safari loading buttons weird

Tags: html, css, safari

I recently built an app, but after deployment, I noticed that Safari seems to be loading css differently. Everywhere I have a type="button", safari adds an odd white box around the element. It looks terrible. I've looked around on the internet and found this:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="button"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

It's the closest I've come to finding a solution, but it doesn't work.

Site: [timetrackers.net](https://www.timetrackers.net)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: NOTE: I just noticed that the CSS for this only affects inputs with type="button". I just use the type for various elements that I want to act like buttons without having that button look

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're talking about Safari's default `:focus` styling.

You can use this CSS to get rid of it:

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I'll post some pictures so you can see it better.